# Linq : Nullable object must have a value

Tags: vb.net, linq

i have this query as linq:

```
  Dim result = (From c In query _
  Where Not bannedCCList.Contains(c.num_reserv)  _                                    
  Group c By c.code_operation, c.code_type _
  Into nbr = Count(CInt(c.Code_bien)), acmp = Sum(CDec(c.TotalAcomp)) _
  Select nbr,  acmp).ToList
```

but i get the error:

> An object that allows Null must have a value

how i can put `acmp=0 if c.TotalAcomp is nothing`

i that my query look like:

```
acmp =IIF(Sum(CDec(c.TotalAcomp)) is nothing,0, Sum(CDec(c.TotalAcomp)) _
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this LinqToSql? What types is`TotalAcomp`? Is it a nullable Decimal?

Comment: it's a nullable double  TotalAcomp = a.Field(Of Double?)("TotalAcomp")

Comment: Something like `acmp = Sum(CDec(If(c.TotalAcomp, 0)))` may work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
acmp =IIF(Sum(CDec(c.TotalAcomp)) is DBNull.Value,0, Sum(CDec(c.TotalAcomp))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don´t use IIF. It´s old VB6 garbage, e.g. it evaluates always both sides even if the true-part returns true. Use [If](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) instead.
2. Your check if the variable is Nothing happens at the wrong place. You have to check it inside the `Sum` function not afterwards.
3. Also use `HasValue` and `Value` properties of nullable types.
   In this case you don´t have to cast any of your expression (besides you casted to the wrong type. If your variable is of type `Double` don´t cast to `Decimal`).

The following code worked for me:

```
acmp = Sum(If(Not c.TotalAcomp.HasValue, 0, c.TotalAcomp.Value))
```